# What is the difference between using API GATEWAY Framework like serverless versus using API Gateway without framework with AWS Management Console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I believe that i meant to use the Serverless Framework or not. Considering this, the difference is more in the deployment process, maintenance and “portability”.

Comment: Serverless Framework, AWS Serverless Application Model (SAM) make your life easier - they absracting things away from you. Both can be used as Infrastructure as Code. 

Really handy tools to get started with AWS Serverless offering.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day, both will produce the same result **but** in the console, things use to take way more time and also lead you to create errors by forgetting to click somewhere or to configure something.

SAM, Chalice, Serverless Framework, Zappa, etc (Infrastructure as Code) will save you time since you can have one or two files that will have all your configurations, instead of going page by page and setting things up.

To answer your question, yes. The difference is in the process of deployment, maintenance, and portability. As long as I know everything that can be made through code can be made via "clickops" with extra effort. The API gateway created at the console will be the same created via code.